# Angular: I have to mute browser tab through javascript. There are no. of audio objects in all components, So I need common script to pause app audios

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, dom-events

Angular: I have to mute browser tab through javascript. There are no. of audio objects in all components, So I need common script to pause app audios.

Number of audio objects in each component with play & pause operations. But now I want to add button through which I can mute the browsers tab. Also If I want then I can enable it.

My current component object like (code snippet as example):

```
//before onInit & constructor function
audioLogin = new Audio();

//in login page loading function
this.audioLogin.play();
```

Like above there are no. of such objects in all components. I have to add toogle button to on/off app sounds. For that I need to mute/unmute browsers tab on that button click.

Please suggest me script (javascript/jquery) or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service which can create any media elements and keep track of it.
Use the service to create instances of media elements.
Call the service function to mute all the media created by the service.

Since as you said you have already created multiple audio/video tags. You just need to refactor a little bit to make this work.
The main thing to note here is "dont create direct new Audio()" you cannot keep track of what you created. just move the creation logic to a service and call the service method.

```
// Create a service class to handle media creations
class MediaService {
  
  media = []; // will hold all media references when created
  
  createNewAudio() {
    // create a Audio instance as usual.
    const audio = new Audio();
    // push the reference of the instance to media array 
    // to perform any operation in future.
    this.media.push(audio);
    
    // return the Audio instance created above.
    return audio;
  }
  
  
  createNewVideo() {
    // create a Video instance as usual.
    const video = new Video();
    // push the reference of the instance to media array 
    // to perform any operation in future.
    this.media.push(video);
    
    // return the Video instance created above.
    return video;
  }
  

  muteAllMedia() {
    this.media.map(m => m.pause());
  }
  
}


// Inject and Use the service to create any media elements
class MyComponent {
    
  constructor(private mediaService: MediaService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    //in onInit function
    this.audioLogin = this.mediaService.createNewAudio();

    //in login page loading function
    this.audioLogin.play();
  }
  
  mute() {
    this.mediaService.muteAllMedia();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried above service code in my app.. but its only pausing currently playing audios.

Comment: You will have to change all the place where you are using new Audio() to the service implementation. Only then service will know about all the media created

Comment: service logic correct, but pause() method only applicable to currently playing audios "only" which is drawback of this service. yes I changed it all places.

Comment: What other audios do you have? and from where it is created?